# Is dynamic and static shared memory allocation allowed at the same time in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I know that in CUDA, it is possible to allocate dynamically a chunk of memory in the shared memory using the keyword extern, e.g.

```
extern __shared__ unsigned s_data_dy[];
```

It is also allowed to declare a static shared variable inside the kernel, e.g.

```
__shared__ float s_data_st[3];
```

My question is - could these two be used at the same time? If they are not allowed to coexist, what if I want the shared memory to store different types of data (say, both floating point and unsigned integer value)?